Add Class Menu Item in Visual Studio Does Not Default to Class Template
For shared project types (other project types don't have this issue) when selecting the "Add Class" menu item:

I don't get the standard C# class items, I get MSBuild Directory.Build.props file and MSBuild Directory.Build.targets file templates:

How do I change it so that Shared Projects open with the default Add Class C# templates?
I found this documentation on how to add items to the dialog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/adding-items-to-the-add-new-item-dialog-boxes?view=vs-2022 but it looks like it is only for adding your own custom templates, not for configuring which template group to show.

It's recommended that you can post your problem in Developer Community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/dotnet
and put link in the comment so that we can follow up.

@FeiXu done: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-Class-Menu-Item-in-Visual-Studio-Doe/10703960

The issue has been confirmed and is under investigation, and you can vote in the report to get Microsoft's attention.
Link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-1754---Add-Class-in-shared-project-/10344964
